# Database table design for college management system

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, user-defined-types

I'm a lion beginner. I'm developing a database for College Management System. For that I decided to create tables. First basically I designed two tables..
They are Student and Department.

```
create table dept_pro
(
dept_id numeric(1) primary key,
name char(20),
hod nvarchar(25),
location nvarchar(10)
);

create table student_pro
(
rollno char(10) primary key,
name nvarchar(25) not null,
dept_id numeric(1) not null foreign key references dbo.dept_pro(dept_id),
ac_year numeric(1) not null check( ac_year in (1,2,3,4)),
sem numeric(1) not null check ( sem in (1,2)),
mobile nvarchar(13),
addr nvarchar not null
);
```

I established a relation between them using a Foreign Key. Now I need to add another set of tables, one for attendance and the other for maintaining marks. There will be maximum of 6 subjects in a semester, and after each semester the subjects change. As the subjects change the corresponding subjects in the attendance table should also change. How can I change the subjects in the marks and attendance table after each semester? And also another important issue is each subject has 3 exams. I tried to create a user-defined type for this each subject having 3 columns exam1,exam2 and exam3(In oracle we create user defined type as a combination of one or more columns).

I'm now using SQL Server. SQL Server is not supporting user-defined datatypes as in Oracle like CREATE DATA..... AS OBJECT.This is further increasing complexity of marks table.

Now how can I solve above problem of maintaining marks & attendance table keeping in mind that the subjects change after each semester. Help me I'm a beginner.

Thanks in advance!!